# Hiding button if PHP != session

Tags: php, jquery

I have a few buttons that I don't want visible to a user if they are not logged it (if $_SESSION['uid'] ='';)  What is the best way to do this?

The buttons that need to be hidden are:

```
    <input type='button' id='forgothide' value='Forgot My Password' >
<input type='button' id='loginhide' value='Login' >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and simple if statement is:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['uid']))
{
  //uid NOT set OR evaluates to FALSE
}
else
{
  //uid is set AND evaluates to true (but not necessarily correct)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Within the HTML/PHP code you simply need to do...

```
[HTML bits...]
<?php
    if(!$_SESSION['uid']) {
    ?>
        <input type='button' id='forgothide' value='Forgot My Password' >
        <input type='button' id='loginhide' value='Login' >
    <?php
    }
?>
[Other HTML bits...]
```

...and all should be well.

Comment: Not checking `isset` or `empty` will throw errors if the key hasn't been set in the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
$buttons = "";

if(!empty($_SESSION['uid']){
$buttons = "<input type='button' id='forgothide' value='Forgot My Password' >
<input type='button' id='loginhide' value='Login' >";
}
```